# Creating a CSV copy of Excel worksheet

Tags: python, excel, vba, csv

I am using this code:

```
import xlrd
import csv

with xlrd.open_workbook('iSolar Transactions (CURRENT).xlsm') as wb:
    sh = wb.sheet_by_index(2)  # or wb.sheet_by_name('name_of_the_sheet_here')
    with open('client_history.csv', 'wb') as f:
        c = csv.writer(f)
        for r in range(sh.nrows):
            c.writerow(sh.row_values(r))
```

It creates a copy well enough, but it does not copy across the formatting of the columns. For example, a `date` column of `2017-04-21` is copied across as a number `41562`. Is there a way to copy across the formatting too?

EDIT:
Using Tiny.D's code:

```
import xlrd
import csv
from datetime import datetime

with xlrd.open_workbook('iSolar Transactions (CURRENT).xlsm') as wb:
    sh = wb.sheet_by_index(2)  # or wb.sheet_by_name('name_of_the_sheet_here')
    column_date = 4 #suppose the first column in your work book is date    
    with open('client_history.csv', 'wb') as f:
        c = csv.writer(f)
        for r in range(1,sh.nrows):
            year, month, day= xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(int(sh.row_values(r)[column_date]), wb.datemode) 
            py_date = datetime(year, month, day)
            c.writerow([py_date]+sh.row_values(r)[1:])
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/warren.si/Dropbox/iShack/Records/#04 Field Operations/#01 client recruitment & management/Client Database/#09 Client Accounts/client_history_tocsv3.py", line 11, in <module>
    year, month, day= xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(int(sh.row_values(r)[column_date]), wb.datemode)
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [xldate_as_tuple](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.xldate_as_tuple-function), below is the amended version based on your code:

```
import xlrd
import csv
from datetime import datetime

with xlrd.open_workbook('iSolar Transactions (CURRENT).xlsx') as wb:
    sh = wb.sheet_by_index(2)  # or wb.sheet_by_name('name_of_the_sheet_here')
    column_date = 4 #suppose the 5th column in your work book is date    
    with open('client_history.csv', 'wb') as f:
        c = csv.writer(f)
        c.writerow(sh.row_values(0)) # write header to csv
        for r in range(1,sh.nrows):
            year, month, day, hour, minute, sec = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(int(sh.row_values(r)[column_date]), wb.datemode) #unpack all values here, not just year, month, day
            py_date = datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute)
            c.writerow(sh.row_values(r)[:3]+[py_date] + sh.row_values(r)[5:])
```

Comment: Thanks @Tiny.D  -I edited the question with your suggestion - but getting an error, see edit.

Comment: @wazzahenry You have to unpack all the values, in your code, you just unpacked 3 variables `year, month, day`, please check my updated answer.

Comment: almost there - this only works when I exclude the headers, and begin the range for actual data. Is there a way to include the headers?

Comment: yep, you can add `c.writerow(sh.row_values(0)) # write header to csv` before the for loop, check the updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *xldate_as_datetime* to convert to Python's datetime format:

```
In [4]: xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(41562, 1)
Out[4]: datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 16, 0, 0)
```

References:

http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime
http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dates.html

Comment: Thanks, but the other columns also have certain formatting, such as currency and decimal places. I was looking for something that would copy the formatting as is, but I can try with this for now.